# how to copy files from solaris to windows

Tags: bash, networking, copy, solaris

Guys this is my first solaris script. I am really sorry if the question is obvious.

Thanks for your answers. We have a Solaris server in which I want to backup the database and then I want to copy the back up to windows back up server.I am planning to write a Solaris bash script and schedule it to run weekly.At first I was thinking of developing a windows batch file but there are several Linux/Solaris commands that I want to be executed and batch file didn't work well, that's why I decided to do it as a Solaris bash script. On Solaris side I created a script for creating the back up, now my problem is to write a script in which I can copy the back up from Solaris to windows back up server over the network.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not clear from your question if you need to write a script that can do the transfer of files in an automated way ... or if this is an ad-hoc requirement. Anyway I'll go with the latter just like the other answers you've got so far.

For anything related to working with Linux/Unix hosts from a Windows box you'll enjoy [MobaXterm](http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/). It's an all-in-one handy tool that wraps all the other tools that you would otherwise have to install (terminal emulator, scp, ftp, X server, etc). I can only recommend it. There's a free version.  (no, I'm not affiliated with MobaXterm in any way).

Here's a picture where I've logged into a Solaris box.

[image]

The right-hand side is essentially an embedded Putty. The left hand-side allows you to upload/download files to/from your remote host, in this case a Solaris host. You would press the buttons I've circled.

MobaXterm has tons of other features packed in a footprint of only 15 Mb.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest option:

```
Start Command Prompt on Windows box, type;
ftp <solaris-ip>
username password
bi
get <file>
quit
```

Second easiest option:

```
Install FileZilla FTP server on Windows
Sit at Solaris box & start xterm
ftp <windows-ip>
username password
bi
put <filename>
quit
```